# How to reduce the size of a pbix file

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am going to use a simple scenario to simplify my question.

I have table A (1000 records). This table has 5 years worth of data
table B (1,000,000 records). This table has 20 years worth of data.

Table A also has a column containing the key to join to table B. The key is to the earliest created record from Table B.

I am using import mode to load this data. When i load both tables, it imports all the records from both tables. I am looking to only bring in the records from table B that join to table A. similar to INNER JOIN.

I tried using the merge funcionality and selecting INNER as join type. In theory, this should only retrieve 1000 records back but when the data is loaded in PowerBI, all records from both tables are loaded into PowerBI desktop.

I am trying to reduce the dataset size by only retrieving the relevant records from table B but not having any luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import Table A and Table B into the query editor, do the inner join to create a new Table C that only has the matching rows.

Then right-click the Table A and Table B and uncheck "Enable Load" so that those tables are only used as connections rather than being loaded into the data model and saved in the PBIX.